# UITextView limit characters and display count left

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm trying limit the characters for a `UITextView` to 200. It gets the data from Firebase Database (if it's available), if not - the `UILabel` that represents the characters left should be hidden - hence, if there's data (text in the text field it should present the `UILabel` with left characters.

I've made sure to conform my `UIViewController` as a delegate of  `UITextViewDelegate` and I've also set up `IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: TextViewX!` (TextViewX is a subclass of `UITextView`) and set the `descriptionTextView.delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad()` method. Once you start typing in the text view, the label count is simply not updated or shown at all.

Also, I'd also would like to change the color of the `UILabel` from green to red when it detects that there are less than 30 characters left.

Here's the code that I have, but it's not working. The characters left is not shown at at all:

```
func textView(_ textView: TextViewX, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
{
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count
    return numberOfChars < 200
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: TextViewX)
{
    let currentCharacterCount = 200 - textView.text.characters.count

    if currentCharacterCount >= 30 {
        descriptionCharacterCountLabel.text = "\(200 - textView.text.characters.count)"
    }
    else
    {
        descriptionCharacterCountLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        descriptionCharacterCountLabel.text = "\(200 - textView.text.characters.count)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it successfully stop you from entering any more text when it reaches 200 chars?

Comment: Are yo sure that your delegate methods are called by putting a break point?

Comment: @Sweeper - it reaches the limit and it stops. @Fangming Ning - Yes, the delegate works. @rmaddy - It's not hidden, it's visible. I see the `UILabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the docs for `UITextViewDelegate`, you will see that `textViewDidChange` is defined like this:

```
optional func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
```

Look at the parameter! It requires a parameter with an external parameter name of `_`!

Look what you've written:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: TextViewX)
```

Your parameter's external name is `textView`!

This is why it does not work.

So, just add `_` and a space before `textView` and change the type of the parameter to `UITextView`.

Comment: I've added `descriptionTextView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for .editingChanged)`  but it shows an error related to the 'for'  saying "Expected expression in list of expressions"

Comment: @Dani You need an `:` after `for`. My bad!

Comment: I figured that was the case and I tried with `:` but it shows another error that states "Value of type TextViewX has no member add target"

Comment: @Dani I've found what's wrong with your code now. See the edited answer.

Comment: OMG! YES! hahaha one tiny `_` and the entire code is invalid! Thank you so much!